# Alternate image alignment on wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

extra newbie coder here, currently working on a WP genesis child theme on a local host, looking for a way so that the images that accompany a post alternate left or right alignment every other post like the example below

http://www.cocorrina.com/

unsure where I should be starting / looking

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Look into [:nth-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

That might help you on your journey.

But to give you a head start, consider you want alternating styles so you would use:

```
.post:nth-child(even){
    float:left;
}

.post:nth-child(odd){
    float:right;
}
```

But do additional reading, researching ability is an important tool to have in your tool belt.